# How to make objects under the Button unclickable?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a strategy game. The map consists of tiles that can be clicked. Also, there is a canvas and a panel that has information about tile. If tile is clicked, the panel becomes visible. I want to make tiles under it unclicked when panel is visible.
How to make it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a Canvas and the button is below the tile in hierarchy and covers the whole of tile, it won't be clickable. Alternatively, you could use Sorting groups or make the tile not interactable when the panel is visible.